# Chrome on iPad fails to download large PDF files

Tags: ios, ipad, google-chrome

Chrome on iPad fails to download large PDF files. For example, if I try to download https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D19-1.pdf (6609 pages) from Google Chrome, it fails. Is there any way to fix or circumvent this issue?

I use iOS 10 with ipad pro 9.7 inch (2016).

Here is a screenshot of the error message:

[image]

I have a 100 Mbps in internet connection and https://www.aclweb.org is quite fast as well so download speed shouldn't be an issue.

The download also fails in Safari:

[image]

Comment: Will it download in Safari without issue?

Comment: @user3439894 The download also fails in Safari (see added screenshot in the question)